# NVMe device only being recognized by UEFI/BIOS after reboot and not during initial cold boot

Tags: ssd, bios, uefi, nvme, hardware-detection

I have recently installed an NVMe M.2 SSD in my desktop computer. Unfortunately, the SSD doesn't gets recognized by the UEFI/BIOS on boot.

I'm aware that there are similar questions on the site with NVMe devices, but those doesn't boot at all. In my case it shows up after a reboot.

It's not available in the boot menu within the UEFI/BIOS. I have both tried with the onboard M.2 slot and with a PCIe adapter card. Choice of physical interface seems to have no significance.

To make the system recognize the SSD, I have to:

1. Boot the computer
2. Go to UEFI settings menu
3. Hit "Save and reset" to reboot the computer
4. It now recognizes the SSD and is able to boot into Ubuntu

If I then afterwards shutdown,and try to boot again, the issue persists. It happens regardless whether the power switch or cord has been disabled/removed.

The issue happens both with and without a secondary SATA SSD installed. The SATA SSD is recognized every time with no issues.

It appears that there are no other apparent issues, at least that I know of, when the SSD has been successfully recognized. Nonetheless, this is a highly inconvenient procedure to follow every time I want to power on the system.

System specifications:

- Asus x99-S (Default BIOS settings). Latest firmware 4101
- Intel i7-5820k
- WD SN550 500GB
- 4x4GB 2133MHz memory
- Nvidia GTX 970

It should be noted that the drive is formatted with LVM2 on LUKS, though I don't believe that this is relevant.

Comment: Hello KaareZ, did you solve that troubles?

Comment: @ratschbumm No, unfortunately not. I ended up returning it and bought a WD Black SN750 instead. No issues

Comment: So sad. Thanks for the info